# How can i access AWS API Gateway API from external server using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am created one AWS lambda function and access this lambda function by AWS API Gateway. I am able to access and get a response from API(API Gateway) when i hit the API directly in the browser but i had got a following error when am try to connect the same API from my local machine or external server by python requests package.

API format : https://endpoint.execute-api.amazonaws.com/cfs/

```
Error: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077410:SSL       routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Local Machine python code:

```
import requests
sms_url = "https://******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"
r = requests.get(sms_url)
```

Comment: Can you pls. provide code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm resolved this issue by using latest version of Python and requests library.
requests==2.9.1
Python 3.4.3